# How to eliminate default namespace when using jQuery.appendTo on an XML document

Tags: jquery, xml-namespaces

I am using jQuery to add an XML Element to my XML document in memory.

```
var newElem = xmlDoc.find("newElem");
if (newElem.length == 0)
  newElem = $("<newElem/>").appendTo(xmlDoc);
```

What I end up with is:

```
<newElem xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></newElem>
```

This xml is sent up to the server in an AJAX call, and using default namespaces in dom4j is a pain. Is there any way to stop the addition of the default namespaces?

I am using Firefox by the way. Could this be a browser specific thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely something jQuery doesn't bother to support, because it simply uses `createElement`, rather than `createElementNS`. The net effect is that it always uses the document (HTML) namespace.

You probably want to use [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS) directly.

Comment: Turns out using createElement works just fine. The key is to use that and not jQuery's internal creation routines

Comment: Okay, I guess it has to do with which document you call it on. jQuery always calls it on `window.document`, whereas you're probably doing it on your own document. Good to hear you've got it working!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `$("<newElem/>")` syntax - that creates a new xml dooc from the 
root, hence the xmlns.

You need to use the non-jQuery plain-javascript createElement() method:

```
var el = xmlDoc.createElement(childname); // Create non-jq element
el = $(el);                               // jQuery-ize it
el.appendTo(xmlDoc);                      // Append using jq object
```

And, while I'm at it, if you're appending to a jQuery-XML node that's not the document, use

```
var el = parent.context.createElement(childname);
```